# Svn mergeinfo starred revisions

Tags: svn, merge

I'm merging revisions made on a branch back to trunk (using TortoiseSVN 1.7.10, Build 23359 - 64 Bit).

When I run the merge info command, e.g.

```
svn mergeinfo https://url/code/branches/project.2.5/@{2012-12-11} https://url/code/trunk -R --show-revs=eligible
```

I get back a revision marked with a star

```
r12345*
```

If I check the svn:mergeinfo property on trunk, that revision number looks like it is merged, e.g.

```
/code/branches/project.2.5:10000-15000
```

So, if I understand it correctly, that revision has been merged, so why would it still be considered *eligible*?

(For context, I have a daily task which monitors all branches and reports when any of them have any outstanding merges so I can keep a track of any branches that are in danger of diverging too badly from trunk. I want to know if I can ignore this revision or whether it needs special attention.)

What does the asterisk in the result mean?

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, but after a colleague pointed out [the merge info section in the manual](http://www.open.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/merge-info.html), in particular the section *Mergeinfo Inheritance and Non-Inheritable Ranges*.

Basically the problem was that there were conflicting `svnmergeinfo` properties in the path - so while at the root level it looked like the revisions had been merged, there were directories further down the tree, closer to the files that had actually been changed in the ineligible revisions, that held conflicting information.

In my situation it was probably because I'd been manually updating the root level properties without realising that some sub-directories had their own, conflicting, prior mergeinfo values.